# Android: Get Website URL from Running Service

Tags: java, android, android-service

I understand that a `Service` class runs in the background in Android and I also understand how to `start` and `stop` a service.

I am just trying to get a better idea of how to use a `Service`.

So say I have a service running in the background. How can I simply get the URL name of a webpage from a web browser app.

Her is my service below:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;
private static final String NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID = "Channel_Id";

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // do your jobs here

    startForeground();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void startForeground() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    startForeground(NOTIF_ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
            NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID) // Create a Notification Channel
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.runningtitle))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.runningtext))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build());
  }
}
```

Comment: "How can I simply get the URL name of a webpage from a web browser app" -- you may want to explain in greater detail what you are trying to do here. For example, are you writing the Web browser?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am not writing the web browser. For example. Say my service is running on my android app. And I navigate to `https://stackoverflow.com` while my service is running. How could I print `https://stackoverflow.com` in my service class when I navigate to that website on Chrome, Samsung internet, Firefox, etc.

Comment: In general, you can't, for obvious privacy and security reasons. The only sort of app that can do something like this is an accessibility service, and there is no guaranteed way that even it can do that, given the wide range of Web browsers.

Comment: @CommonsWare so it's practically impossible to get name of a URL from an Android service?

Comment: You are welcome to see if any of your targeted browsers offer a plugin mechanism that you can use.